# how to get the dynamically genarted text Using Selenium Webdriver and pass it onto sql query?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how to get the dynamically genarted text Using Selenium Webdriver and pass it onto sql query ?

I am not a developer, but I know java programing concept, I am learning selenium and java for automation testing. have never used so far. and I need to get a text and sent it to sql query

Comment: What are your programming skills? Which language do you use? What you tried so far?

Comment: I am not a developer, but I know java programing concept, I am learning selenium and java for automation testing. have never used so far. and I need to get a text and sent it to sql query.